# How to export Users using PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, permissions, phpmyadmin

Does anyone know how to export users using PHPMyAdmin?  I've got the entire structure ported over to a new server but the users didn't make it.

I understand it involves the mysql user table, but it would be awesome if there was a non-destructive way so I can be assured it won't mess up users on the new server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use SQL; try using [`SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) syntax to load your users into a file on your system.

You might have to fudge the primary keys but you can do this by editing the file. For instance, as long as you have fewer than 1000 users, you can add 1000 to each primary key so they don't conflict with users in the new database. You can do this with a script, or with vim, or even with Excel.

Then copy the file to your other server and use [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html).

Comment: A slightly alerted version of that worked great.  Much easier than I thought. Thanks!

Comment: Sure would have been nice if this included steps or an explanation of how to do this.